# Linux function for user prompt

Tags: linux, bash

I do not understand why I get this output

```
Delete content?  aas
Delete content?  a
Delete content?  s
Delete content?  n
ATS=Please enter Y or N.
Please enter Y or N.
Please enter Y or N.
```

with following script

```
#!/bin/bash

function prompt2() {
    while true; do
        read -p "$1 " answer
        case $answer in
            [Yy] ) answer=0; break;;
            [Nn] ) answer=1; break;;
            * ) echo "Please enter Y or N.";;
        esac
    done
    return $answer
}

a=$(prompt2 "Delete content? ")
echo "ATS=$a"
```

I expect that after entering wrong characters I would immediately get line `"Please enter Y or N."`   printed to the screen but it gets printed only after I enter one of expected characters. Also the value that got returned by the prompt function is unexpected.

---

**Thank you all** for the explanations! For me (who is used to OOP) this "workflow" is something new.

Comment: You store the output of your function in a variable and it is not sent to /dev/stdout. While the implementation is correct, you do not see the lines "Please enter Y or N" due to the `a=$(...)`. This variable will contain those lines. They are printed due to the line `echo "ATS=$a"` as they are stored in the variable `a`. The other lines appear because `read` sends directly to /dev/stdout. You could redirect your `echo " Please enter Y or N"` line also there.

Comment: `read -p` writes to standard error. `/dev/stdout` is, well, standard output.

Comment: As @chepner says. Update my comment with a replacement /dev/stdout to /dev/stderr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command substitution captures the function's standard output, not its return code.

The simple non-intrusive fix is to change `return` to `echo` inside the function, and to change the diagnostic message to print to standard error (so you don't capture the "Please answer Y or N" text as well).

```
prompt2() {
    while true; do
        read -p "$1 " answer
        case $answer in
            [Yy] ) answer=0; break;;
            [Nn] ) answer=1; break;;
            * ) echo "Please enter Y or N." >&2;;
        esac
    done
    echo "$answer"
}
```

I also got rid of the silly Bash-only `function` keyword for you.

**Alternatively,** don't change the function, and have the calling code examine the return code.

```
if prompt2 "Delete things?"; then
    rm -rf /
else
    echo "Wise choice."
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Because that's not how `$()` works in bash.

```
a=$(echo 'hi')
echo $a
```

Will yield 'hi', even though `echo`, having completed without errors, will return 0.

The return code is stored as `$?`

```
prompt2 "Delete content? "
echo "ATS=$?"
```

will give the answer you want

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  As @tripleee says, the command substitution is capturing standard out.  So, the echo replacing the return is needed.

If you want to see the error message, redirect it to standard out

```
echo "Please enter Y or N." >&2
```

Hope this helps